# JBoss Forge does not respond to command

Tags: java, maven, jboss, build, jboss-forge

Following setup:

1. I am using Win 7, Java 1.7
2. I successfully installed JBoss Forge 2.15.1
3. I added `/.../forge-distribution-2.15.1.Final/bin/` to my PATH
4. I can start forge with `forge`

But none of the commands works:

`[D:\]$ list-commands`

`Command: list-commands was not found`

The same goes for `new-project`.

BUT: `version` command goes fine.

I could use any advice, as I see nothing on the documentation page (and I mean nothing: something does not work with my browser?)

EDIT: Version 1 of Forge did the job before. I installed the new version and changed the `bin`-path.

Comment: The same problem is stated in the jboss forum, but their answer does not work. https://developer.jboss.org/thread/252492

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most commands have been renamed in version 2.x.

```
list-commands -> command-list
new-project -> project-new
```

More info: http://forge.jboss.org/documentation